# FFmpeg : Check if the aac bitstream is malformed or not

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to upload few sets of videos on my server and later play them in the HTML5 video tag. But some of them are not playing.

I checked the audio stream and video stream of the video, they have **AAC** and **H264** codec respectively.So nothing seems wrong to me.

Then I tried re-encoding it, i got the following message:

```
malformated aac bitstream, use -absf aac_adtstoasc
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Operation not permitted
```

However I don't want to encode the videos before upload and **just need to check** if video has a malformed aac or h264 bitsream.

> PS. Users are limited and will be provided with videos h264 and aac
>   encoded for the upload.

Comment: Can you compare the output of an ffprobe and/or mediainfo command on a file that plays correctly and one that doesn't in order to see if there's a difference in streams encoding or metadata ?

Comment: Yeah... I did that and found the cause ,why it was not playing on HTML5 .The culprit was **MPEG-2 transport stream**.. Thanks :)

Comment: Good. If your issue is solved, you are welcome to self-answer with a solution for future references.